# How to display author(authorized user) image on a published content item in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am a beginner in Orchard. I want the author's name and image on his/her published content page. While I was able to display the name by making an alternate .cshtml file for the content area and using model

```
    @Model.ContentItem.CommonPart.Owner.NormalizedUserName
```

I am not able to get any model for the Author/admin image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, there is no user/author image by default in orchard, you can add "MediaLibraryPickerField" to "UserPart", and then use it as a profile image.

Comment: @mdameer Thank your for the information,it was my fault that i didn't explained my question clearly(apologies).I added MediaPickerField to the user type but still unable to display it.

Comment: Ok, to display it use this code (@Url.Content(Model.ContentItem.UserPart.ImageField.Url)), FYI, there is two media modules in Orchard CMS, and every module has it's way to display images.